# How can I use scp/ssh in a cron script without entering a password?

Tags: raspbian, remote, security, password, scp

I have a script that goes out to 5 other Rpi3 computers and collects data from them using scp and puts it all out on a flash drive.  (Then later it gets picked up from the master Pi by a Windows Task for backup to a hard drive.)

It needs to be put into cron so I don't need to initiate it manually.
But it prompts for the password of each remote Pi as it runs.

How do I solve this?

For reference, you can see a description of my entire Rpi3 network in my answer to this question:

[How can I connect 5 Raspberry Ppi's?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66562/how-can-i-connect-5-raspberry-ppis/66572#66572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is really easy.

First, I generated a public key on my master unit that can be shared with the other computers.

```
ssh-keygen
```

Just press enter to the three questions.

Then, I appended my public key to the other servers like so:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

where remote-host is a name of the other server from my /etc/hosts file

It will prompt you to accept the other host's key - you answer yes (not just y)
Then it will prompt you for the other server's password.

I ran that the ssh-copy-id -i command for each of the 5 remote Pi3s, using their name from MASTER's /etc/hosts file.  It works with plain IP addresses also.

That's it.  Now my script runs with no prompting.

Best of all, it works in cron so I don't even need to be here when it runs.

Comment: It works!  I use it every day now.  This same method works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS also, after openssh-server is installed.